# How to calculate page views in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am looking to calculate how many times people have viewed my news on my site, and I don't know how to do that. I've searched at Google but I can't find an answer.

Is there any instruction on how to do this?

Comment: Searched at Google but could not find an answer? Lie! Or you might using wrong keywords. Search for "php visitor count" or similar phrases. Rearrange keywords etc. You should be able to find something. You don't need to find specifically for codeigniter as if you know how to program, you know how to add it on your controllers. Also, "visits counter" will vary depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the counter, codes may vary depending on your requirements.

[Here's](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-PHP-Hit-Counter) an example, 4 easy steps on how to make a counter.

To incorporate this with your website, include this on your controllers. I suggest have a main controller, which will be the parent and everything else will inherit the parent.

That should be on a custom function, and each function that provides "news/page" should call that `visits counter` function.

Comment: nice code sir.. thank you..

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution may be as follows:

Create a table called visits in database ( contains only one row )

Include the file visits.php in all the pages you wish to track

**visits.php**

```
<?php
//connect to database

mysql_query("UPDATE visits SET no_of_visits = no_of_visits+1");

?>
```

Comment: that's good sir, but how I can implement it into my link? and where the code should be placed? thanks